# how to display only the title from the tuple in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have the following code which creates the database...

```
type Title = String
type Singer = [String]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]

type Film = (Title, Actor, Year, Fans)

type Database = [Film]  

filmDatabase :: Database
filmDatabase = [("Wrapped up", ["Olly Murs"], 2014, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
            ("Someone Like you", ["Adele"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),
```

I then have used the following code to search for A fan and display all the music they like.

```
fanOfFilms :: Fan -> Film -> Bool 
fanOfFilms fan (t, _, _, f) 
  |elem fan f = True
  |otherwise = False

givenUser :: Fan ->[Film]
givenUser fan = filter (fanOfFilms fan) testDatabase
```

I want to now take this code and make it only display the titles. How do i do this? I have tried using map and tried to use pattern matching but cannot get it to work?!

code I tried

```
   titleOnly :: (t, a, y, f) -> (t, f)
   titleOnly (t, _, _, f) = (t, f)`
```

I then tried linking this to FansFilms but it looks messy and i don't know how to correctly

Comment: well i tried writing a function:

       `titleOnly :: (t, a, y, f) -> (t, f)
       titleOnly (t, _, _, f) -> (t, f)`

and then i tried using the titleOnly to call givenUser so it then only print the title and fan but this didnt work

Comment: sorry done this now @bheklilr

Comment: I would recommend using the actual type aliases instead of what you have. Try `filmTitle :: Film -> Title`; `filmTitle (t, _, _, _) = t`. This is basically what you have, I changed the function name and it's only getting the title of a film. You can define `filmActor`, `filmYear`, and `filmFans` very similarly through pattern matching.  If you wanted to get both the title and the fans of all the films in your database, you could then combine `filmTitle` and `filmFans` into a new function, but this would often be done with a lambda, such as `map (\f -> (filmTitle f, filmFans f)) filmDatabase`.

Comment: okay I see what you have done to only get the film name, but how do i apply this function of `filmTitle` to my `givenUser` function used above

Comment: Your `givenUser` function returns a `[Film]`.  Try checking the type of the `map` I gave you above in GHCi with `:type map (\f -> (filmTitle f, filmFans f))`.  Also remember that `type Database = [Film]`.

Comment: I see, I am new to Haskell and the types confuse me, your explanation really helped. Thank you

Comment: You'll find that as you learn Haskell the types are very important.  It is far more important than in any other language I've used what the types of values and functions are.  Whenever you see something new in Haskell, try using `:info symbol_name` (or just `;i`) or `:type symbol_name` (or just `:t`) in GHCi to get more information about it.  The types are very rigid in Haskell so it's useful to know a bit more about them when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that, given a `Film`, returns its title:

```
filmTitle :: Film -> Title
filmTitle (t, _, _, _) = t
```

And then map this function over the list of `Film`s returned by `givenUser`.

```
givenUserTitles :: Fan -> [Title]
givenUserTitles fan = map filmTitle (givenUser fan)
```

Comment: Thank you, i am just getting my head around higher order functions so forget about them when it comes to having to use them. This really made things clear thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first item in a tuple, use `fst`.  You can get the second item with `snd`, which is useful because many times you will use ordered pairs as tuples.  The most readable way to get the title out of the tuple I think would be:

```
title :: Film -> Title
title (t,_,_,_) = t
```

To get the fans,

```
fans :: Film -> Fans
fans (_,_,_,f) = f
```

Now what you want to do is match up a fan with all of the titles they are a fan of, correct?  This means that you will need to check each film title if the fan is a member of the list of fans.  You can do this with the `elem` function.

Let me know if any of this does or doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lens` package (not that I'm saying that you should use it), you can use `_1`, `_2` etc ...

Example

```
("title", "actor", "year", "fans") ^. _4
>>> "fan".
```

However, in that situtation, you probably should use a record.